# SQL - Multiple Descriptions - Return First Value

Tags: sql

SQL newbie question here.

I have a table:
Table - [Products] - With columns below

```
ProductID, ProductDesc
DRILL01    Drill Bits
DRILL02    Drill Other
DRILL01    Drill Set
DRILL01    Drill Bits Set
....
```

Looking to return the first match e.g

```
DRILL01    Drill Bits
DRILL02    Drill Other
```

I've tried group by with no look and think I may need a TOP 1 option, but    can't seem to get my head around it. done plenty of searching but I must be missing something.

any help would he great.

Comment: Is `ProductID` the pk? ie should the values be unique?

Comment: What is the SQL statement you are using that is not working?

Comment: No such thing as the "first" match. Rows don't have inherent order in SQL. If you don't specify an ordering, then each query execution may give you a different row.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY timestamp_col) AS r
      FROM tab)
WHERE r=1;
```

In order to get stable results you have to decide how to get "first" value per `ProductId` group. For example by sorting by some kind of timestamp/identity column.